# Compatibility of code between 2 laptops & CMake

Tags: cmake

I am syncing my code between a desktop and a laptop, but when I try to build the program in my laptop I get the following error message:

```
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/mylatoppath is different than the directory /home/mydesktoppath where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: The source "/home/...." does not match the source "/home/..." used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
```

Any ideas how to fix it? 
Note that I regularly have to sync them since I want to work on both of them

Comment: Delete the cache?

Comment: You mean the CMakeCache.txt file? Is it generated after every build?

Comment: Yes. I don't know.